# injecting a dll with createremotethread

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

how does createremotethread execute a dll inside a process? One of the parameters it uses is the loadlibraryA. So I get the part where it executes the loadlibrary function within the process. It should then make a context switch to kernel mode. Does the dll get executed by the process with the loadlibrary function return value?

Comment: Please describe the programming problem you are having where you think the solution involves understanding how CreateRemoteThread loads a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other `LoadLibrary` call, the dynamic loader will call into your injected DLL's `DllMain` function with the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` reason code. The code in your `DllMain` can take it from there, though I would strongly advise against doing too much from within `DllMain` itself due to the loader lock.

Comment: Yes, in `DllMain`, create another thread to do the heavy lifting

Comment: so the dynamic loader loads the dll and then it fills in the table in the executable and then the exe will call dllmain in the same thread which called loadlibrary?

Comment: why isn't getprocaddress function used to call dllmain?

Comment: Because LoadLibrary() calls it for you, and because you can't call DllMain() directly anyway because it is not an exported function that GetProcAddress() can find. LoadLibrary() executes the DLL's startup code, which then calls your DllMain() internally as needed.

Comment: what happens when dllmain is called?

Comment: @icealys: what do you mean, *what happens*?  The code you put in the DLL's DllMain function is executed.  For example, you can put in a call to CreateThread to launch a separate thread that runs your DLL's main function.